# How to pipe output of one method to the input of the other in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, piping

Lets say I have an array of functions as below

```
var updateCountryToCanada = function (items) {
    return items.map(i => {i['country'] = 'Canada'; return i});
}

var strip_punctuation_from_name = function (items) {
    return items.map(i => {i['name'] = i['name'].replace('.', '-');
    return i}); 
}
```

and an array of items as below

```
var items = [{'name': 'John.Joo', 'height': 160, 'country':'US'},
    {'name': 'Isla', 'height': 180, 'country':'France'},
    {'name': 'Sam'}];
```

I put all my functions in an array

```
var funcs = [updateCountryToCanada, strip_punctuation_from_name]
```

Now, my question is how can I in JavaScript call functions one at a time and pass all items to them in a way that the result of the first function become the input to the second and so on? I want to chain them together (piping).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`.reduce()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
var result = funcs.reduce((r, f) => f(r), items);
```

This calls the `(r, f) => f(r)` function for each item in the `funcs` array. The first time, `r` will be `items`. For each subsequent one `r` will be whatever value was returned from the previous call. `f` is the current item from `funcs`.

Expand the snippet to see the results:

```js
var updateCountryToCanada = function (items) {
    return items.map(i => {i['country'] = 'Canada'; return i});
}

var strip_punctuation_from_name = function (items) {
    return items.map(i => {i['name'] = i['name'].replace('.', '-');
    return i}); 
}

var items = [{'name': 'John.Joo', 'height': 160, 'country':'US'},
    {'name': 'Isla', 'height': 180, 'country':'France'}];

var funcs = [updateCountryToCanada, strip_punctuation_from_name];

var result = funcs.reduce((r, f) => f(r), items);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not properly piping (as `>` or `|` in Unix), but you can do something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < funcs.length; i++) {
  items = funcs[i](items);
}
```

```js
var updateCountryToCanada = function (items) {
  return items.map(i => {i['country'] = 'Canada'; return i});
}

var strip_punctuation_from_name = function (items) {
  return items.map(i => {i['name'] = i['name'].replace('.', '-'); return i}); 
}


var items = [{'name': 'John.Joo', 'height': 160, 'country':'US'},
    {'name': 'Isla', 'height': 180, 'country':'France'},
    {'name': 'Sam'}];

var funcs = [updateCountryToCanada, strip_punctuation_from_name];

for (i = 0; i < funcs.length; i++) {
  items = funcs[i](items);
}

console.log(items)
```

Answer (score 0):

As a relatively simple approach, you can call:

```
functionOne();
```

If `functionOne()` looks something like:

```
function functionOne() {
    [... CODE ...]
    var result = [...WHATEVER...];
    functionTwo(result);
}
```

and `functionTwo()` then looks something like:

```
function functionTwo(input) {
    var input = input;
    [... CODE ...]
    var result = [...WHATEVER...];
    functionThree(result);
}
```

Then the result of `functionOne()` will be the input of `functionTwo()`, the result of `functionTwo()` will be the input of `functionThree()` etc.